# Smoother filtering of ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table and the tr are generated by a `ng-repeat`. When I filter them (in this case to change page), all the rows are replaced with new ones. But for a split second, we see both the old filtered rows (page 3 for instance) and the new filtered rows (say page 4). This is pretty ugly as it screws up my design for a tenth of a second.

Is there a way to make the transition seamless? I had the `ng-repeat` animated before (AngularJS 1.2.0RC1), but the same thing happened (for longer though) and I thought that it would be fixed by disabling animations. Unfortunately, it didn't fix it.

Have any ideas?

[edit]

This is the CSS I used for my animations, before disabling it

```
.animate.ng-enter {
  -webkit-animation: enter_sequence 0.2s linear; /* Safari/Chrome */
  -moz-animation: enter_sequence 0.2s linear; /* Firefox */
  -o-animation: enter_sequence 0.2s linear; /* Opera */
  animation: enter_sequence 0.2s linear; /* IE10+ and Future Browsers */
}
@-webkit-keyframes enter_sequence {
  from { opacity:0;}
  to { opacity:1;}
}
@-moz-keyframes enter_sequence {
  from { opacity:0;}
  to { opacity:1;}
}
@-o-keyframes enter_sequence {
  from { opacity:0;}
  to { opacity:1;}
}
@keyframes enter_sequence {
  from { opacity:0; }
  to { opacity:1; }
}

.animate.ng-leave {
  -webkit-animation: leave_sequence 0.2s linear; /* Safari/Chrome */
  -moz-animation: leave_sequence 0.2s linear; /* Firefox */
  -o-animation: leave_sequence 0.2s linear; /* Opera */
  animation: leave_sequence 0.2s linear; /* IE10+ and Future Browsers */
}
@-webkit-keyframes leave_sequence {
  from { opacity:1; }
  to { opacity:0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes leave_sequence {
  from { opacity:1; }
  to { opacity:0; }
}
@-o-keyframes leave_sequence {
  from { opacity:1; }
  to { opacity:0;}
}
@keyframes leave_sequence {
  from { opacity:1; }
  to { opacity:0; }
}
```

Comment: Have you played with your `enter` and `leave` css styles with your animation? Do you have a jsfiddle or some code we can see? In my AngularJS projects I noticed what I believe to be similar to what your describing but it cleared up when I started using the `$routeProvider`

Comment: I added some CSS, maybe you can see some tweaks I could apply there? If it's not enough I could try to build a jsFiddle, but given the complexity of the project right now it would be pretty hard to port it there to show the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried delaying the transition in css? Works for me

Comment: Delay it for double the time the animation lasts, in my application I normally use, for an animation time of 0.75 seconds:


    transition-delay: 1.5s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1.5s;